# How to compare time_struct with datetime.datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get rid of the data that's more than 7 weeks old. I converted str timestamp to time_struct but when I want to compare with timedelta I get this error.

> TypeError: unorderable types: time.struct_time() < datetime.datetime()

Here's my code

```
start = new_programme.get('start')
start_time = time.strptime(start, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S -0000')
print(type(start_time))
seven_weeks = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=7)
print(type(seven_weeks))
is_more_than_7_weeks = start_time < seven_weeks
```

stdout

```
<class 'time.struct_time'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use datetime.strptime:

```
start = new_programme.get('start')
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S -0000')
print(type(start_time))
seven_weeks = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=7)
print(type(seven_weeks))
is_more_than_7_weeks = start_time < seven_weeks
```